# C# Form: Identity_Insert set to OFF - How do I fix this?

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255)
);
```

Comment: You are not explaining what you need to fix. Identity insert generally *should* be OFF. Don't turn it ON to resolve an issue that might be a bad idea - generating your own numeric primary keys, for instance.

Comment: 1) don't spam unrelated tags to your question , I removed unrelated tags 2) tag your database as well 3) your question is not clear ,provide the code that is giving you the error as well as the error message

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.